# An analogous gradient on a triangle in Inkscape

Tags: inkscape, gradient

I have a rectangle, shown below, which has a gradient so that the top and bottom edges fade to black.  I wish to reshape this this rectangle into a triangle (like the one pictured) so that top and bottom edges of the triangle still fade to black.

To produce the triangle below I converted the rectangle into a path, removed one of the nodes on the left, and then centered the remaining node on the left.

[image]

The gradient I am trying to implement, however, should look more like the one below (which I created in Microsoft Word).  Notice how the directions of the gradient are in line with the sides of the triangle.

[image]

Are there any ways to create a triangle that has the gradient pattern shown above?  Thanks all.

Comment: This is a little confusing. It sounds like you are asking how to make the exact triangle you made in the example. Could you clarify a bit?

Comment: My apologies.  I am finding this problem difficult to describe.  I added an additional picture that will hopefully clarify what I am aiming to create.

Comment: ah, thanks. Yes, that's much clearer! Alas, I do not know of a way to do that in Inkscape. Inkscape is great, but, admittedly, it's gradient tool isn't particularly advanced.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As DA01 mentioned the gradient options in Inkscape are somehow limited. If you don't mind using two objects instead of one here's a guide:

Create a rectangle with a gradient, transform it to a path and drag two nodes to create a triangle. Hit `F2` and drag the `Linear gradient end node` to the tip of the triangle.

[image]

Now create a rectangle, cover the upper half of the triangle with it, select the rectangle and afterwards the triangle and cut it with `Path > Difference`.

Now duplicate and mirror your new triangle.

[image]

If you try to join them the gradient will be lost unfortunately.

Comment: Just the type of work-around I was looking for.  Thanks boo2060!

Answer (score 0):

I realise you're after an Inkscape solution, but I was able to make what you're after in Photoshop by creating a gradient, turning it into a Smart Object, then distorting it.

If nothing else, maybe it'll serve as an example of what you're after?

[image: Squashed Gradient]